# Using NSString as an Array of NSStrings?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I just came across a line of code that was written by a co-worker and I've never seen this before in Obj-C. It looks like poor form and I want to change it, but it seemingly works (the app is working as expected) and I don't even know what to change it to.

```
NSString **stringArray= new NSString *[numberOfStrings];
```

Is this OK? Would an NSArray of NSStrings make more sense?

EDIT: In order to properly free the array from memory, are any `release` calls needed? Currently, all I see is `delete [] stringArray;`.

EDIT 2: This seems to properly remove the array from memory:

```
for (int i=0; i < numberOfStrings; i++)
{
    [stringArray[i] release];
}
delete [] stringArray;
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, that would be Objective-C++, right?

Comment: Let's say it's not the most beautiful solution I've seen. An NSArray of NSString makes much more sense in Objective C, and with an NSArray the code will play nicely with ARC too.

Comment: It it **not** Objective-C++, it's just a C-style array of `NSString` pointers. Nothing C++ about it.

Comment: @BenS What is this "`new`" in C or Objective-C? I must be behind the times... while the resulting *type* is the same, `malloc/free` and `new/delete` *must* be correctly paired.

Comment: This is a mix of C, C++ and Objective-C. You should ask your coworker what their reasoning was to write it like this. Some kind of strange guideline at your office, maybe?

Comment: And that is what I was getting to.. to free the object from memory properly, are any `release` calls needed? Right now all I see is `delete [] stringArray;`.

Comment: @Kevin_TA You must correctly release/manage *all* contained `NSString` objects per Obj-C rules. Likewise, the object (of type `NSString**`) created here with `new` must also be `delete`d somewhere (or ownership transferred as appropriate). The one really nice advantage of `NSArray` is that it is still entirely within the Obj-C lifetime/management rules. If the `NSString**` object lifetime is only that of the function, it might be more appropriate to use C99 VLAs (variable-length arrays).

Comment: It appears to be perfectly legal Objective-C.  (I'll let the nit-pickers decide whether C or C++.)  The main question would be whether there's any significant advantage to doing things this (relatively obscure) way vs using an NSMutableArray.  The one fairly compelling reason for using this scheme would be that an NSMutableArray cannot contain nil values, but a C array can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He is using Objective-C++ (you should be able to verify that in the 'file type' on the right panel for the file in xcode4).

the `new` keyword is creates a new array of (NSString *) with `numberOfStrings` size.

To answer your question, an `NSArray` would very likely be more manageable, especially if there are different developers on the code. To use a C++ array there may have been performance issues but that depends on the context of that code.

Comment: +1 FWIW: The syntax here is: `new T [count]`: in this case `T` is `NSString*` so it's the same as `new NSString* [numberOfStrings]`, which might be easier to "see", even though it has the `*` cuddling the braces in the post... let the style wars begin! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Using an `NSArray` might be more legible to someone without a C background, this is just a plain old C array filled with `NSString*`, perfectly valid but quite different from an `NSArray` instance.

Both make sense, but if the users of that array are expecting a C-style array rather than an `NSArray` instance, there might be a lot of refactoring involved.